# Running the same linq query on multiple IQueryable in parallel?

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-extensions

**Situation:** I have a `List<IQueryable<MyDataStructure>>`. I want to run a single linq query on each of them, in parallel, and then join the results.

**Question:** How to create a linq query which I can pass as a parameter?

**Example code:**

Here's some simplified code. First, I have the collection of `IQueryable<string>`:

```
    public List<IQueryable<string>> GetQueries()
    {
        var set1 = (new List<string> { "hello", "hey" }).AsQueryable();
        var set2 = (new List<string> { "cat", "dog", "house" }).AsQueryable();
        var set3 = (new List<string> { "cat", "dog", "house" }).AsQueryable();
        var set4 = (new List<string> { "hello", "hey" }).AsQueryable();

        var sets = new List<IQueryable<string>> { set1, set2, set3, set4 };

        return sets;
    }
```

I would like to find all the words which start with letter 'h'. With a single `IQueryable<string>` this is easy:

```
query.Where(x => x.StartsWith("h")).ToList()
```

But I want to run the same query against all the `IQueryable<string>` objects in parallel and then combine the results. Here's one way to do it:

```
        var result = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        Parallel.ForEach(queries, query =>
        {
            var partOfResult = query.Where(x => x.StartsWith("h")).ToList();

            foreach (var word in partOfResult)
            {
                result.Add(word);
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

But I want this to be a more generic solution. So that I could define the linq operation separately and pass it as a parameter to a method. Something like this:

```
        var query = Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("d") && x.IsRemoved == false)
            .Select(x => x.FirstName)
            .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);

        var queries = GetQueries();

        var result = Run(queries, query);
```

But I'm at loss on how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the first thing that you wanted was a way of taking a sequence of queries, executing all of them, and then getting the flattened list of results.  That's simple enough:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Foo<T>(IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>> queries)
{
    return queries.AsParallel()
            .Select(query => query.ToList())
            .SelectMany(results => results);
}
```

For each query we execute it (call `ToList` on it) and it's done in parallel, thanks to `AsParallel`, and then the results are flattened into a single sequence through `SelectMany`.

The other thing that you wanted to do was to add a number of query operations to each query in a sequence of queries.  This doesn't need to be parallelized (thanks to deferred execution, the calls to `Where`, `OrderBy`, etc. take almost no time) and can just be done through `Select`:

```
var queries = GetQueries().Select(query =>
    query.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("d")
        && !x.IsRemoved)
    .Select(x => x.FirstName)
    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName));

var results = Foo(queries);
```

Personally I don't really see a need to combine these two methods.  You can make a method that does both, but they're really rather separate concepts so I don't see a need for it.  If you do want them combined though, here it is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Bar<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<IQueryable<TSource>> queries,
    Func<IQueryable<TSource>, IQueryable<TResult>> selector)
{

    return queries.Select(selector)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(query => query.ToList())
        .SelectMany(results => results);
}
```

Feel free to make either `Foo` or `Bar` extension methods if you want.  Also, you *really* better rename them to something better if you're going to use them.

Answer (score 5):

First - given your current implementation, there is no reason to use `IQueryable<T>` - you could just use `IEnumerable<T>`.

You could then write a method which takes an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` and a `Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>>`, to build a result:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<U>> QueryMultiple<T,U>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> inputs, Func<IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable<U>> mapping)
{
     return inputs.AsParallel().Select(i => mapping(i));
}
```

You could then use this as:

```
void Run()
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<YourType>> inputs = GetYourObjects();

    Func<IEnumerable<YourType>, IEnumerable<YourType>> query = i => 
       i.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("d") && x.IsRemoved == false)
        .Select(x => x.FirstName)
        .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);

    var results = QueryMultiple(inputs, query);
}
```

Comment: this is interesting, but I thought the general idea of this question and the usage of queries was to have fewer calls against the providers by building/generating expression trees that are **to be** evaluated/parsed/processed by whatever provider you're running it on/against; that way the provider can take that (probably complex) expression and run it one time in whatever manner it determines to be the most optimal.. does this code sample accomplish that?

Comment: @BrettCaswell The OPs code is all LINQ to Objects and handled in memory, so it's not an issue there.  This works in memory, though - so it wouldn't handle that.

Comment: thanks for the response, I suppose you're right.. I was thinking regardless of whether it was SQL, Entity, or Object.. that the underline concept would still be to build an expression tree. I looked into PredicateBuilders and LINQkit a bit, and it seemingly comes down to creating Expression.Lambda<delegates> that uses InvocationExpressions (invoke) to buildup the QueryExpression. There is a little trickery (swapping) with an EntitySet Extension Method

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, wouldn't the 'better' route here be to get `(from foo in bar).Expression` of each of the queryables and build the expression tree? in a manner that uses invocation of the query preceeding it in that iteration

Comment: @BrettCaswell Depends on the usage - that's MUCH slower and more difficult code if you're using LINQ to Objects...